# map id field fluent nhibernate`

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

If I have a Table Bob with a foreign key to Frank how do configure the mapping such that the class Bob looks like this (without the class Frank):

`public class Bob{ 
     public int FrankId{get;set;}
     ///not public Frank Frank{get;set;}
}`

Comment: if it is a foreign key to frank why not have it as reference to frank in code and kick FrankId?

Comment: Because I would prefer not to load franks data, lazy or otherwise.

Comment: Nhibernate is smart enough to not load frank data when accessing `Bob.Frank.Id` only when accessing other properties of Frank where you need to load it anyway